# How to detect the screen position in a system with multiple displays?

Tags: java, screen, multiple-monitors

I got two monitor, one is 1440*900, another is 1920*1080. I can rearrange the monitor in many ways like that:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

Also, I can mirror the screen as well. How can I get these kind of information using pure Java only? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure only the Display Driver will have this kind of information. Think this is the best you can do in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877570/java-getting-resolutions-of-one-all-available-monitors-instead-of-the-whole-de

Comment: @JasonC Yeah I don't know that regular Java can do much beyond what we posted; Android has far more of support for that kind of thing but don't think that qualifies as 'pure java'

Comment: @Durandal Oh, good link. Yeah, you can do what's in that link, essentially, except you can use `getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds()` to get actual relative coordinates of the monitors; you could actually use it to generate the picture TedWong posted, if you wanted.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, my clumsy editing made our comments collide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [`GraphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getScreenDevices%28%29), you can get the screen bounding rectangles from each device, e.g.:

```
GraphicsDevice[] screens = GraphicsEnvironment
    .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
    .getScreenDevices();

for (GraphicsDevice screen:screens)
    System.out.println(screen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds());
```

On my dual-monitor system it displays:

```
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1600,height=900]
java.awt.Rectangle[x=-320,y=-1200,width=1920,height=1200]
```

You can use `getDefaultScreenDevice()` to figure out which one is the primary monitor. There's a lot of other info you can get from a [`GraphicsDevice`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) which might be useful.

Comment: ok Jason thanks... this at least helping me out to recognized how many monitors currently available. Hehe... great!